# Trying to reference "this" referencing to a current string object. Not sure if I'm doing this right

Tags: java, class, object, this

**Scenario**
quiz problem, final exam tomorrow and this problem makes NO sense to me, someone please please please show me the code segment that would fit the criteria. everything I try has failed. my biggest problem is I have no idea how to reference "this". So I have no idea if I am doing it right or not my teacher will not give me a yes or no answer, I am going to post my attempt at the code below and hopefully someone will correct my mistakes. I would be forever in your debt!

**The question**

> Write a BigInt CLASS function int countDigits() that returns the number of significant digits in the BigInt object (i.e "this"). Assume we are using the string representation for the BigInt (leading zeros not removed) significant digits start with the left-most non-zero if BigInt has a value of 0 the number significant digits is 1`

**What I've Tried**

```
public int countDigits()
{
  int i = 0;
  while(this.number.charAt(i)=='0')//this.number will reference a string object
    i++;
  String str = this.number.substring(i,number.length();)//this.number will reference the string object
  System.out.println("leading zeros removed : "+str);
  System.out.println(" number of significant digits  = "+str.length());
  return str.length();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does this not do what you expect it to?

Comment: It does, BUT I want to know if I am referencing to my string object (which is number) correctly and am I aloud to store `this.number.substring(x,y) ` into a string str

Comment: Assuming `CountDigits` (btw. method names are conventionally not capitalized in Java) is a member of class `BigInt` which has an other member `number` of type `String`, then `this` refers to the runtime instance of `BigInt` on which you call the method `CountDigits`, and `this.number` to its string representation, if you will. But `this` is optional, so if you write `number` instead of `this.number`, you should be referencing the same value. **Edit:** What is the parameter `n` for in your code? You don't seem to use it (or I'm just blind). Also, you probably intend to return `str.length()`

Comment: As is stated above, it's impossible to say with only a single method provided without any of the other class information. Assuming the typical formation of classes, I would say "yes", but it's impossible to say based on what you've shown.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to put `n` in this code I was just looking at the wrong thing. so @KuluLimpa can I store `this.number.substring(x,y)` into a string like  I have it? I just don't know if thats the correct way to store the string object into a variable. My teacher is making us use "this" which I do not feel at all comfortable with. Yea I ment to return, I was just working on it in main so I forgot it.

Comment: @krillgar what other information do you need? this is all the information allotted for the problem.

Comment: @Jeff The other information needed would be the context of `CountDigits`, i.e., its enclosing class with the member `number`. You may also want to add an example of how you'd call the method (including object instantiation)

Comment: I think your so knowledgeable of the subject you are over thinking the matter lol we are not aware of any of that information. only instructions are to use "this" to reference our string object, and a solution using "this" and return the number of significant digits. I think you can assume everything that must be the case is the case.

Comment: No, because in everything you've shown us, there is no context for `this`. That keyword is only valid in the context of an instance of an object. What you've given us does not provide that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a field `number`, these two expressions:

```
this.number
number
```

Are identical in effect in your code. You only need to prefix a field name with `this.` when there's a local variable or parameter of the same name as the field, thus *shadowing* it.

---

Although not directly answering your question, more food for thought, since you have a String to store your number, consider a String approach to your method:

```
public int countDigits() {
    return number.replaceAll("^0+", "").length();
}
```

This one-line solution first produces a String with all leading zeroes removed, then simply uses its length.

Comment: So is my approach completely wrong? if so what is incorrect?? my teaching is making us use this. what can I void in my code? what lines of code do I NEED and do not need.

Comment: No need to refer to `this.number` - just `number` is fine (`this.number` will work too, but it's "code clutter"). Your approach is OK - don't worry :)

Comment: is storing my my `this.number.substring(x,y)` into another string syntactically correct?  thanks man!

Comment: @Jeff If it compiles it is syntactically correct. Storing this temporary result in a temporary variable of type `String` is also good practice; reassigning `this.number = this.number.substring(x, y)` would however, in your special case also be semantically correct, as it only discards the leading (nonrelevant) zeros. Note that `str` does only exist as long as the method `countDigits` is executed while `this.number` lives even after the method returns.